# ReactiveSearch how to stop initial query on load

Tags: react-native, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

So I've got ReactiveSearch working fine but I've noticed on the initial load it performs a query to fetch items - given my index will have perhaps a million items in it I'd ideally like to turn this off and only return results from the autosuggest?

```
       <ReactiveBase
        app="tths-shop-items"
        url="my-es-cluster"
        credentials="user:password"
        >
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles2.container}>
            <DataSearch
              componentId="searchbox"
              dataField={[
                'name'
              ]}
              placeholder="Search"
            />
            <ReactiveList
              componentId="results"
              dataField="name"
              size={7}
              showResultStats={true}
              pagination={true}
              react={{
                and: "searchbox"
              }}
              onData={(res) => {
              return (
                <View style={styles2.result}>
                  <Image source={{ uri: res.image.replace('http', 'https') }} style={styles2.image} />
                  <View style={styles2.item}>
                    <Text style={styles2.title}>{res.name}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )}
              }
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </ReactiveBase>
```

EDIT
I also tried adding the default value in order to try and stop the initial query returning data. But it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
defaultValue="3245423 kjhkjhkj 2kj34h12jkh 213k4jh12"
```

EDIT 2:

I've also tried defaultQuery in the following format and added it to the reactiveList and dataSearch components this gives me an error which is undefined is not an object 'this.defaultQuery.sort' - if I add sort to both queries it makes no difference:

```
              defaultQuery={() => 
                {
                  query: {
                    match_none: {}
                  }
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's one answer, you store the value that you click via the searchbox in state and then fiddle with the defaultQuery from there. Note default query does match_none: {} if there's no search text.

It's a bit inefficient as you still do a query that returns nothing, but it works - I'll leave this question open to give any better answers time to come up.

```
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <DataSearch
              componentId="searchbox"
              dataField={[
                'name'
              ]}
              placeholder="Search"
              queryFormat="and"
              noInitialQuery={true}
              onValueChange={(value) => { 
                if(value === ''){
                  this.setState({searchText: null})
                }

              }}
              onValueSelected={(value, cause, source) => {
                  this.setState({searchText: value.value})
                }
              }
              />
            <ReactiveList
              componentId="results"
              dataField="name"
              size={7}
              showResultStats={true}
              pagination={true}
              react={{
                and: "searchbox"
              }}
              defaultQuery={()=> {
                if(this.state.searchText !== null){
                  return {
                    query: {
                      match: {
                        name: this.state.searchText
                      }
                    }
                  }
                } else {
                  return {
                    query: {
                      match_none: {}
                    }
                  }

                }
              }}
              onData={(res) => {
              return (
                <View style={styles2.result}>
                  <Image source={{ uri: res.image.replace('http', 'https') }} style={styles2.image} />
                  <View style={styles2.item}>
                    <Text style={styles2.title}>{res.name}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )}
              }
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but I stumbled upon the same problem.

My solution looks a little bit different - with the onQueryChange prop.

```
onQueryChange={
  function(prevQuery, nextQuery) {
    if ('match_all' in nextQuery['query']) {
      nextQuery['query'] = { match_none: {} }
    }
  }
}
```

This will disable the ResultList with all results showing and only show results after you've selected any filter or entered a search term.

Comment: Ooo nice, i'll give that a go! Welcome to StackOverflow - if that works I'll mark this as the correct answer as it's a better solution

Comment: Thanks :) Did you give it a go?

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer was very useful but I changed the *defaultQuery* to use the original query in the event a search term is present:

```
defaultQuery={()=> {
  if(this.state.searchText !== null){
    return {
    }
  } else {
    return {
      query: {
        match_none: {}
      }
    }

  }
}}
```